# iOS 15 This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified

Tags: ios

I have developed an iOS App and I have trying to install a beta demo via a .ipa file. I have tried loading the file through Configurator and Finder and had no luck.

I have an iPhone Distribution certificate Issued by: Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority and is coming up with valid message in Keychain. I have a UDID number on device on Apple Developer along with a provisioning profile and Bundle ID that matches.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that after adding the device UDID in the Apple Developer Portal, you didn't recreate the IPA? Whenever a registered device is added, it would only be able to install the app after the app had been rebuilt (As far as I understand, this is because in Ad-Hoc distribution, the list of registered devices is embedded within the app binary)

Answer (score 4):

Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Select AppleID -> Select team -> Click on Download Manual Profiles.
This will refresh the new added devices with UDID and then you can rearchive the .ipa. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: To add to this: Also check if the correct API version is installed in Xcode. I got the error with an iOS 16 device (ipa had been exported with iOS 14 or 15) and when I connected it to the Mac to test it directly, instead of using the ipa file, Xcode complained that the iOS 16 API wasn't installed. After installing it, it handled the signing process automatically and a newly exported ipa didn't cause the problem.